# How to get the current location temperature in android

Tags: android, temperature

I am new in Android Development. I have created app on Geocoding to get current location. Now I want to get the temperature of the current location too. I found in stackoverflow that there is no thermometer in any Android device to calculate the room or location temperature and it can be only made by getting temperature from internet. I am unable to implement this portion. Please give me any idea or code snippet to achieve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: An idea? I would research web services provided by organisations like (in the uk) http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/ to see if they provide ways to get temperature based on a location. Then research JSON to parse these data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best way of doing this is accuweather API. I also used it in weather widget. Its very simple to use. Just follow the link http://api.accuweather.com/developers/weatheralarmsAPIguide

Comment: it is paid unfortunately